# ElasticSearch in Azure Container Instance (Preview)

Tags: azure-container-instances

The following command creates a container instance of elasticsearch:latest image:

```
$ az container create --image elasticsearch:latest --name es -g rg-es --ip-address public --memory 4 --cpu 2
```

According to:

```
$ az container show --name es -g rg-es -o table
```

the instance is running yet when I browse to the assigned IP the browser responds with: "can't open the page because the server where this page is located isn't responding".

Creating the container from the azure portal doesn't make any difference.

Has anyone come across this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic search doesn't expose port 80 by default. But you can pass port
 —port 9200 to expose the default port. This is probably the issue you're hitting.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm 100% sure I tried that before and didn't work, for some reason it works now passing --port 9200. Thanks.